# Should the navigation property be in the constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I want to achieve that one subscription can have many members. My code looks like this:

```cs
public class Member
{
    public Member(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
    }
#pragma warning disable CS8618
    protected Member() { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; } 
    public Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}


public class Subscription
{
    public Subscription(string name, double price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }
#pragma warning disable CS8618
    protected Subscription() { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    protected List<Member> _members = new();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Member> Members => _members;
    
    public void AddMember(Member member)
    {
        if (member is null || _members.Contains(member))
        { 
            return; 
        }
        _members.Add(member);
    }
}
```

I do not know if I should add the navigation property (Subscription) in the member class to the constructor because if I do so, everyone can create a new subscription when they call the constructor of the member class. EF Core automatically sets the navigation property and the foreign key if I add a new member with AddMember(member). What are the advantages and disadvantages if I use the one or the other way to achieve this?